Issue with refreshing auth tokens in React with Axios
I'm learning how to use Axios and TanStack Query (previously React Query) for interacting with backend that use token authentication. I am wondering how to properly refresh the tokens.
My backend is using the following architecture (source)
I tried to use Axios with axios-auth-refresh for refreshing the access token but im getting the backend problems when I try to use refreshToken endpoint.
Here is my axios client with interceptor:

export const client = axios.create({
  baseURL: import.meta.env.VITE_API_URL || "http://localhost:8001/",
  withCredentials: true,
});

client.interceptors.request.use(
  async (config) => {
    const accessToken = await getAccessTokenFromCookies();
    console.log("ACCESS TOKEN in interceptor: " + accessToken);

    if (accessToken) {
      config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${accessToken}`;
    }

    return config;
  },
  (error) => {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);

export const setHeaderToken = (token: string) => {
  if (
    token &&
    client.defaults.headers.common.Authorization !== `Bearer ${token}`
  ) {
    client.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
    console.log(
      "Authorization header set:",
      client.defaults.headers.common.Authorization
    );
  }
};

export const removeHeaderToken = () => {
  delete client.defaults.headers.common.Authorization;
};

createAuthRefreshInterceptor(client, refreshAuth, {
  statusCodes: [401], // Intercept 401 Unauthorized errors
  pauseInstanceWhileRefreshing: true,
});

For refreshing the tokens im using axios-auth-refresh with the following function:

export const fetchNewToken = async () =\> {
const refreshToken = getRefreshTokenFromCookies();
console.log("REFRESH TOKEN before fetching new: " + refreshToken);

try {
console.log("BEGINNING OF REFRESH TOKEN : " + refreshToken);
const response = await client.post("/auth/refreshToken", { refreshToken });
const { accessToken, refreshToken: newRefreshToken } = response.data;
console.log(
"NEW TOKENS after auth/refreshToken :",
accessToken,
newRefreshToken
);

    await setTokensInCookies(accessToken, newRefreshToken);
    
    console.log("NEW ACCESS TOKEN set:", accessToken);
    
    return accessToken;

} catch (error) {
console.error("Failed to refresh token:", error);
return null;
}
};

// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
export const refreshAuth = async (failedRequest: any) =\> {
try {
const newToken = await fetchNewToken();

    if (newToken) {
      failedRequest.response.config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${newToken}`;
      setHeaderToken(newToken); // Ensure this sets the header correctly
    
      return Promise.resolve(newToken);
    } else {
      console.error("Failed to refresh the token, redirecting to login.");
      return Promise.reject(new Error("Token refresh failed."));
    }

} catch (error) {
console.error("Error during token refresh process:", error);
return Promise.reject(error);
}
};

I set the access and refresh tokens in cookies in login query.

export function useLogin() {
return useMutation({
mutationFn: async (requestBody: { email: string; password: string }) =\> {
try {
const { data } = await client.post("/auth/login", requestBody);
const { accessToken, refreshToken } = data;

        setTokensInCookies(accessToken, refreshToken);
        setHeaderToken(accessToken);
    
        return { ok: true, data };
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Login error:", error);
        return { ok: false, error: error || "Login failed" };
      }
    },
    onSuccess: () => {
      console.log("Token set, ready for authenticated requests");
    },

});
}

I'm having a problem with refreshing the token after it expires.
I guess that the problem in this line is const response = await client.post("/auth/refreshToken", { refreshToken }); but I don't know why, because when I use API client such as Insomnia for refreshing the token everything works fine.

What is the problem?
